# Consumindo API MARVEL com Angular 8

Tags: angular

Estou iniciando em Angular/cli 8 e acompanhando um vídeo no Youtube para aprendizado. Neste vídeo diz que devemos informar a chave pública e o *hash* para acessar as informações JSON vindas da API.

Estou fazendo exatamente como no vídeo do Youtube. Na hora de startar o servidor e ver o resultado no `localhost:4200` me é apresentado as seguintes mensagens de erro abaixo:

```
GET https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts=1&apikey=&hash= 401 (Unauthorized)
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized", url: "https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts=1&apikey=&hash=", ok: false, …}
```

Já fiz o cadastro na Marvel e já recebi a chave pública e a chave privada, só não tenho o *hash* ainda.

Como posso gerar esse *hash* para colocar no código?

Abaixo o meu código sem as chaves.

```
export class CharactersApiService {

  PUBLIC_KEY = '';
  HASH = '';
  URL_API = `https:gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts=1&apikey=${this.PUBLIC_KEY}&hash=${this.HASH}`;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllCharacters() : Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.URL_API)
    .pipe(map((data: any) => data.data.results))
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Passo 1:** Você precisa criar a conta gerando assim uma **`chave pública`** e uma **`chave privada`** no site da Marvel.

**Passo 2:** Após ter as chaves você precisa criar o **`hash`**, como?

- Pegar o **timestamp** + **chave privada** + **chave pública**

  ```
             1        cd4aafe016...    0065ff6881...
  ```
- Juntar estes valores em um site criador de hash como [este aqui](http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php) e criar a hash
- Será criado um hash parecido com este **77014510e99dbdc7763cb969af14b3ef**

**Passo 3:** Fazer o service

```
export class CharactersApiService {

   PUBLIC_KEY = '0065ff6881...';                   //  <= chave publica
   HASH = '77014510e99dbdc7763cb969af14b3ef';      //  <= hash criada
   URL_API = `https:gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts=1&apikey=${this.PUBLIC_KEY}&hash=${this.HASH}`;

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

   getAllCharacters() : Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get<any>(this.URL_API)
      .pipe(map((data: any) => data.data.results))
}
```

> **A partir daí você já estará com acesso a API, tendo como resultado algo como este abaixo que coloquei apenas uma parte, pq o retorno da Api é bem extenso:**

```
{"code":200,"status":"Ok","copyright":"© 2019 MARVEL","attributionText":"Data provided by Marvel. © 2019 MARVEL","attributionHTML":"<a href=\"http://marvel.com\">Data provided by Marvel. © 2019 MARVEL</a>","etag":"012e092bb6230a8080c4f4b88e782025f7f08a44","data":{"offset":0,"limit":20,"total":1492,"count":20,"results":[{"id":1011334,"name":"3-D Man","description":"","modified":"2014-04-29T14:18:17-0400","thumbnail":{"path":"http://i.annihil.us/u/prod/marvel/i/mg/c/e0/535fecbbb9784","extension":"jpg"},"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1011334","comics":{"available":12,"collectionURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1011334/comics","items":[{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/21366","name":"Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #14"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/24571","name":"Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #14 (SPOTLIGHT VARIANT)"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/21546","name":"Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #15"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/21741","name":"Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #16"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/21975","name":"Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #17"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/22299","name":"Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #18"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/22300","name":"Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #18 (ZOMBIE VARIANT)"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/22506","name":"Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #19"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/8500","name":"Deadpool (1997) #44"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/10223","name":"Marvel Premiere (1972) #35"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/10224","name":"Marvel Premiere (1972) #36"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics/10225","name":"Marvel Premiere (1972) #37"}],"returned":12},"series":{"available":3,"collectionURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1011334/series","items":[{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/series/1945","name":"Avengers: The Initiative (2007 - 2010)"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/series/2005","name":"Deadpool (1997 - 2002)"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/series/2045","name":"Marvel Premiere (1972 - 1981)"}],"returned":3},"stories":{"available":21,"collectionURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters/1011334/stories","items":[{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/19947","name":"Cover #19947","type":"cover"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/19948","name":"The 3-D Man!","type":"interiorStory"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/19949","name":"Cover #19949","type":"cover"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/19950","name":"The Devil's Music!","type":"interiorStory"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/19951","name":"Cover #19951","type":"cover"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/19952","name":"Code-Name:  The Cold Warrior!","type":"interiorStory"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/47184","name":"AVENGERS: THE INITIATIVE (2007) #14","type":"cover"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/47185","name":"Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #14 - Int","type":"interiorStory"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/47498","name":"AVENGERS: THE INITIATIVE (2007) #15","type":"cover"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/47499","name":"Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #15 - Int","type":"interiorStory"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/47792","name":"AVENGERS: THE INITIATIVE (2007) #16","type":"cover"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/47793","name":"Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #16 - Int","type":"interiorStory"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/48361","name":"AVENGERS: THE INITIATIVE (2007) #17","type":"cover"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/48362","name":"Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #17 - Int","type":"interiorStory"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/49103","name":"AVENGERS: THE INITIATIVE (2007) #18","type":"cover"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/49104","name":"Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #18 - Int","type":"interiorStory"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/49106","name":"Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #18, Zombie Variant - Int","type":"interiorStory"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/49888","name":"AVENGERS: THE INITIATIVE (2007) #19","type":"cover"},{"resourceURI":"http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/stories/49889","name":"Avengers: The Initiative (2007) #19 - Int","type":"interiorStory"},
```

Comment: Obrigado LeAndrade por responder, mas amigo, o mesmo erro persiste ==  erro: 401 - não autorizado.   Outra coisa, gerei o HASH como mandou de duas formas diferentes: com os três valores juntos sem espaços, com os três valores com o sinal de mais entre is valores e a caixa de seleção ativa abaixo e com os três valores com espaços entre eles e a caixa de seleção ativa abaixo.  ACAIXA DE SELEÇÃO ATIVA É: Treat multiple lines as separate strings (blank lines are ignored)  ==  Obrigado